# SQL doing data comparisons for table joins

Tags: c#, sql, database, join

I am working on a C# application that uses a database. I need to join two tables together, but they are linked strangely. One table has letters identifying the data like A, B, C, etc. and the other has string values identifying the type like "small" or "large"

I need to join the tables so that the values in the first table's column with the code 'a' link to the other table's column with the value of "small" and the values that are 'b' or 'd' link to the other table's value of "large"

What is the best way to do this using standard SQL. Is there some way I can have extra conditionals in the join statement or is it best to do something like this in a where clause?

Thanks,

-Jake

Comment: I think , it's better if you do this stuff in C# code !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to handle this would be to have an intermediate table that maps the the values. You can then add this table to your statement and use it join the main tables together.

Answer (score 0):

Make a case statement to map a to 'small' and b,c,d... to 'Large' in your first table,with the new field join the tables

Answer (score 0):

Make an intermediate table or query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT CASE col WHEN 'A' THEN 'small'
                  WHEN 'B' THEN 'large'
                  WHEN 'D' THEN 'large'
                  ELSE NULL
         END AS col
   FROM one
) x
JOIN two t
    ON x.col = t.col
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45eb0/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think you can use Common table expression , to select those values you need , as well as the column which has A,B,C values.  Then use CTE to join your second table. it will looks like the following.

;WITH A_CTE (columns) 
 
AS 
( 
   select column1,columnb, CASE A_B_C_COLUMN WHEN 'A' THEN 'LARGE' WHEN 'B' THEN 'SMALL' WHEN 'C' THEN 'TINY' END AS ColumnC 
)
select * from A_CTE JOIN TABLEB ON A_CTE.ColumnC = TABLEB.ConditionColumn

if you can provide more detail, happy to write the SQL Statement for you.